# Ember-CLI 'Ember Update' command

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm an ember noob going through the ember-cli 101 book. To date, I've been using the upgrade worklow on the ember-cli website, [here](http://www.ember-cli.com/#upgrading).

Messing around with the ember-cli help, in terminal, I came across an 'ember update' command that says it updates to the newest ember-cli version.

Is there a difference between the two? Is the 'ember update' command going to be what to use in the future and just isn't fully implemented yet?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: After some googleFu, [this](https://hackpad.com/Ember-CLI-01032015-Kzs87z4sHVT) is all I could find about 'ember update' (bottom of page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove old version then install new ember cli version 
ex:

1. npm uninstall -g ember-cli -- Remove old global ember-cli
2. npm cache clean -- Clear NPM cache
3. bower cache clean -- Clear Bower cache
4. npm install -g ember-cli@2.8.0 -- Install new global ember-cli

[Visit](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases)

Answer (score 3):

The `ember update` command has been removed:

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4415

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the `ember update` command works as it is not listed in the docs and cursory tests reveal that it seems to always think I'm on the latest version of ember-cli even if I'm not.  There is also an [open issue on Github](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2187) regarding this.

I'd recommend sticking with the steps listed in the ember-cli website until the command is made functional.

Answer (score 0):

`ember update` does works. It does the same steps defined in the ember-cli release section.